# How to save state when back to previous page in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to get original state when exist screen and return back to current screen in react native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is the situation where you are navigated to screen B from screen A. Now you are returning back to screen A.

As react holding the latest state values in this scenario, you have to do it manually.

Inside componentDidMount(), consider this method

```
this._navListener = this.props.navigation.addListener("willFocus", () => {
     // reset the state variable here...     
});
```

this willFocus method has been called every time that particular page coming to the front view. Try this If you are still not clear, please revert back to me.